# Coding technique for counting number of responses from different instances

Tags: c++

I have a class `CallerA`, and a class `CalleeB`.

 Class `CalleeB` has a queue and finishes job asynchronously. 
For instance, if `CalleeB` has a function `enqueue(int input)` and `CallerA` calls `CalleeB.enqueue(1)` and `CalleeB.enqueue(11)`, result of input 11 can be returned earlier than input 1.

 Now, `CallerA` creates 10 `CalleeB` instances.

 `CallerA` will input from 1 to 5 incremental to random `CalleeB` instances, and from 6 to 10 incremental to random `CalleeB` instances, and from 11 to 15 and so on.

`CallerA` will wait for callback to receive results from `CalleeB` instances and if all 1~5 result is received, `CallerA` will do something. Also if `CallerA` receives 6 to 10 is received, `CallerA` will do something.

 Of course, it is possible that input 1 and 6 goes to same  `CalleeB` instance and 6 is returned earlier than 1.

 Is there an efficient technique to implement `CallerA` counting result from `CalleeB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an efficient technique to implement CallerA counting result
>   from CalleeB?

Sure, CallerA just needs to keep track of which results he has received back, so that when he receives all 5 results in a set he can act on them.

The way I would do it would be to have CallerA maintain an `unordered_map<int, Result>`, and whenever a result is received from a CalleeB, place it into the unordered_map and then check to see if the other 4 results for that set are also present in the unordered_map; if so, remove them from the unordered_map and process them.

Alternatively, you could keep an 10-item array of 5-item sub-arrays of results, and place each result into the appropriate slot (slotIdx=i%5) in the appropriate sub-array (arrayIdx=i/5) as it comes in.  After placing a result in the appropriate sub-array, you could either check the slots of the sub-array to see if they are all populated, or alternatively you could increment a counter specific to that sub-array, and when the counter gets to 5, the array must be full.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! would unordered map be faster than map?

Comment: A little bit faster -- lookups on an unordered_map are O(1) and on a map they are O(log(N)).  Using the arrays+counters method would probably be faster than either type.  That said, at the scale you're looking at (50 items), you'd be unlikely to be able to measure the difference; if you were planning to scale it up to thousands or tens of thousands of items, you might.